# Python Selenium Webdriver, Firefox Version Compatibility on CentOS

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, centos

I'm trying to run UI Automation using Python Selenium Webdriver on CentOS.
Which versions of Firefox are compatible.

I tried multiple combinations with Selenium 2.47.1->3.3.1, FF 24 -> FF 45
I even installed geckodriver for the latest Selenium release.

None of them are working for me. Please suggest a working combination of these version.

I mostly get the belwo error while opening firefox with webdriver.

```
self._get_firefox_output())
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: "The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. 
The output was: b'No protocol specified\\nError: cannot open display: :1.0\\n'"
```